# Connect Virtual entity with Cosmos DB

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-online

I am trying to pull Cosmos DB data into CRM and want to use these record in Lookup field. What I have achieved as of now is, I am able to connect Cosmos DB with Virtual Entity and when I use VirtualEntity in *Advanced Find* I can see all the record. In Cosmos, I have AccountGUID as text, OpportunityGUID as text and OpportunityName.

**Problem**
When I click on the lookup I can see only one record (In cosmos DB I have 5 record) and after selecting listed record in lookup when I click on that record, it's not getting redirect to Virtual entity form. Can someone guide me how can i achieve this task?

Comment: Can you open the Virtual Entity Form when opening the record from Advanced Find?

Comment: @Filburt - No, it's throwing error. And when i do mouse over on record which is showing on Advance find, the GUID in the URL is showing 00000-00000-0000 format. It's means mapping is not happening in correct way.

Comment: It looks like you need to step back to your Virtual Entity configuration and research the error message you receive.